# Creating A Dataframe From a Previously Read In Text File in Python

Tags: python, pandas

I am new to Python, so please forgive me if the way I have written some code isn't pretty. But, I am trying to create a DataFrame with a single column of values that I loaded in from a text file because I need to be able to have an index with that column of data. Here is an example of what I have:

```
import pandas as pd
file = open('sample.txt','r')
for data in(raw.strip().split() for raw in file):
    y = data[5]
```

Now, I want to be able to turn that y variable which is a list of values into a data frame with pandas so I can have an index.

Here is an example of what the values of the y variable look like:

```
553.01
551.37
597.75
635.81
720.56
766.11
```

Comment: Can you give an example of how the data in your txt file looks like?

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you do it.

```
import pandas as pd
data =[]
with open('test.txt', 'r+') as f:
    for line in f:
       data.append(line.strip())
#Create dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
#Change column name
df.columns = ['value']
#View the data
df.head()
```

I hope this is the result you need.